# Apache cgi scripts not rendering

Tags: apache, cgi

I am getting their source. I am running `apache 2.4.7`

The .pl script is executable (meaning it has the correct permissions) and it prints out fine html when I run `./script.pl` in the terminal.
It is in: `/var/www/cgi-bin/`

I am trying to configure the default virtual host to run cgi scripts.
So in this file: `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

I added the following:

```
  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin/">
            Options +ExecCGI
            AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny 
            Allow from all 
        </Directory>
```

The problem is somewhere in the configuration whoever I can't figure out where.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that in `2.4.7` the cgi module is not turned on by default. This is how you solve the problem:

```
sudo a2enmod cgi
sudo service apache2 restart
```